# Can't use external library in my app

Tags: module, typescript

I created a Gui library that works fine when i test it from within the project. Now i want to use it as a library, for my sound generation application.
Seems simple, but i couldn't get anything despite many changes in my references or compiler options...

I use 1.6.2 version of typescript, target `es5`, use `commonjs` for`module` in both `tsconfig.json` files .  `moduleResolution` is `classic`.

I don't know if that matters, but i use `experimentalDecorators` and i output `declaration` file and inlined source map.

What i have so far is like (simplified version):

---

••• Library files •••

```
shapes.ts
shapes/rect.ts
shapes/roundrect.ts
```

shapes.ts is the main module. Since i've read that files are already modules, i did not use the `module`keyword.

```
// shapes.ts
/// <reference path="./shapes/rect.ts"/>
/// <reference path="./shapes/roundrect.ts"/>
export * from "./shapes/rect.ts";
export * from "./shapes/roundrect.ts"
```

--

```
// rect.ts
export class Rect {
  x : number;
  y : number;
  ... 
}
```

--

```
// roundrect.ts
/// <reference path="./rect.ts"/>

import {Rect} from "./rect.ts";

export class RoundRect extends Rect {
  cornerRadius : number;
  ... 
}
```

---

••• App files •••

for the App file, i made many attemps, i would like to be able to write :

```
var MyRect = new Rect();
```

or :

```
var MyRect = new Shapes.Rect();
```

So i tried a lot of import syntax, since no two blogs or docs says the same about this syntax :

```
import  * as Shapes from '../../shapes/dst/shapes';
```

Or

```
import Shapes = require('../../shapes/dst/shapes');
```

Or

```
import  {Rect, RoundRect} from '../../shapes/dst/shapes';
```

Or

```
var Shapes = require('../../shapes/dst/shapes');
```

( Or all above examples from the `src` and not the `dst` folder) .

All those examples get marked as a wrong path in the editor.

I also tried all examples above with or without :

```
/// <reference path="../../shapes/rect.ts"/>
```

Rq the path is marked correct with reference, but when using a reference path, there are a lot of 'Cannot find module' errors.

---

So bottom line, i always get, for the module import, the same error :

```
Cannot find module '../../shapes/dst/shapes'
```

¿¿¿ How can i use my lib ???

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple classes exported inside a file, it makes sense to use a module.
If you'd rather export a class as a module itself, you can try `export =` 
Example:

```
class RoundRect {
    ....
}
export = RoundRect;
```

http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules-export-

Comment: Thanks for this tip, i'll try. However this doesn't apply to the main lib file shapes.ts, which has many export. And i still don't get why each of my `require` attempts claims the path is wrong when a `reference path` with the same path works.